# How many different terms in this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

How many different terms in this sequence?
$u_k=\left\lfloor \frac{k^2}{2013}\right\rfloor$, $k=1,2,3...2013$

Thanks so much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:  when $k$ is small enough, $(k+1)^2-k^2 \lt 2013$ and the floor will have you hit every number.  When $k$ gets larger, the change will be larger than $2103$ and all the values will be distinct.  A little thought about the transition and you are there.

Answer (score 0):

Each $k$ is different, so the answer should be $2013$ right?

Comment: No, because of the floor.  $\lfloor \frac {1^2}{2013} \rfloor = \lfloor \frac {2^2}{2013}\rfloor =\lfloor \frac {3^2}{2013}\rfloor =0$

Comment: Not right, with k=1,2,...,44 then $u_k=0$